# Javascript regex with non-capturing group as two alternatives

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I would like to create a regex, which allows you to input values like `Name` and `Surname`. But I have some restrictions:

- Capital first letter (only one) and then other small letters
- After the previous one, user can use `'`, `-` or  (whitespace) and after that apply same rule as at first point

I almost achieve this, but something still doesn't work properly. Here is my creation:

```
/^[A-ZÀ-ž]{1}[a-zà-ž]+[\s\'-]{0,1}(?:(?=[\s\'-]{0,1})[A-ZÀ-ž]{1}[a-zà-ž]+|(?=[\s\'-]{0,1})[a-zà-ž]+)$/i
```

I want to use it in Javascript with function `.test(value)`. Unfortunately it also accepts these:

- `Test`
- `Test -`
- `Test-`
- `test`
- `Test`
- `Test-test`
- `TTest`
- `Test'test`

What I want to be accepted and allowed are those:

- `Test`
- `Test-Test`
- `Test Test`
- `Test'Test`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this... What I'm missing here?

Comment: Try [`^[A-ZÀ-ž][a-zà-ž]+(?:[\s'-][A-ZÀ-ž][a-zà-ž]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/AKaWFq/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for answer, but unfortunately it still accepts unwanted words like: `Test-test`, `TTest` etc. Also it allowed in my application to put the `test`.

Comment: It does not, I forgot to turn off the `i` modifier, see https://regex101.com/r/AKaWFq/3, but probably you really want to use [`^[A-ZÀ-Ž][a-zà-ž]+(?:[\s'-][A-ZÀ-Ž][a-zà-ž]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/AKaWFq/4).

Comment: So the question is why this one is still working: `Łóźćż'żłóźćęą` ??

Comment: The `À-Ž` (`\u00C0` - `\u017D`) range includes all lowercase letters, too. What alphabet(s) do you want to support?

Comment: Really? I thought its like with `A-Z` and `a-z`... I want to support latin and want to this with possible short solution.

Comment: You cannot actually make it short if you want to match uppercase and lowercase letters separately. Surely there is a way to shorten the code though. I will post an answer then.

Comment: I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Just a sec, it is a bit time-consuming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174240/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-lui).

Comment: If you plan to only support Chrome and other ECMAScript 2018 compatible browsers, you may use `/^\p{Lu}\p{L}+(?:[\s'-]\p{Lu}\p{L}+)*$/u`

Comment: How to apply this solution in Java? Because I put the same on Java and Javascript and it's not working...

Comment: That is even easier in Java since Unicode is fully supported in Java regex. Use `String pattern = "(?U)^\\p{Lu}\\p{L}+(?:[\\s'-]\\p{Lu}\\p{L}+)*$";`. I only add `(?U)` to let `\s` match any Unicode whitespace.

Comment: But it is equal to solution from those comments or from your answer where you split it up between uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: Ah, forgot about that, you need to only match lowercase letters after initial uppercase. I edited the answer below. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/798blT/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match lower- and uppercase letters separately. Currently, your `À-ž` range for European letters includes all lower- and uppercase letters, and even some non-letters.

Here are the ranges you need:

**Uppercase (basic European)**

- Basic Latin — Uppercase Latin alphabet: `[A-Z]`
- Latin 1 Supplement — Letter items - Uppercase: `[À-ÖØ-Þ]`
- Latin Extended A — European Latin - Uppercase letters: `[ĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİĲĳĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŊŌŎŐŒœŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸŹŻŽ]`

**Lowercase (basic European)**

- Basic Latin — Lowercase Latin alphabet: `[a-z]`
- Latin 1 Supplement — Letter items - Lowercase: `[ß-öø-ÿ]`
- Latin Extended A — European Latin - Lowercase letters: `[žſāăąćĉċčďđēĕėęěĝğġģĥħĩīĭįıĵķĸĺļľŀłńņňŋōŏőŕŗřśŝşšţťŧũūŭůűųŵŷźż]`

The pattern you need is

```
/^[UPPER][lower]+(?:[\s'-][UPPER][lower]+)*$/
```

where `UPPER` and `lower` are uppercase and lowercase letter ranges/sets.

So, let's build the pattern.

```js
var upper = '[A-ZÀ-ÖØ-ÞĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİĲĳĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŊŌŎŐŒœŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸŹŻŽ]';
var lower = '[a-zß-öø-ÿžſāăąćĉċčďđēĕėęěĝğġģĥħĩīĭįıĵķĸĺļľŀłńņňŋōŏőŕŗřśŝşšţťŧũūŭůűųŵŷźż]';
var rx = new RegExp("^" + upper + lower + "+(?:[\\s'-]" + upper + lower + "+)*$");
// Let's test
var tests = ['Test ','Test - ','Test-',' test','Test-test','TTest','Test\'test','Test','Test-Test','Test Test','Test\'Test', 'Łóźćż\'żłóźćęą'];
for (var s of tests) {
  console.log(s, '=>', rx.test(s))
}
```

**NOTE** there are more letters that can be used in European languages. For more details, see [Unicode Utilities](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BLatin%7D&g=&i=) for reference.

**NOTE 2**: if you plan to only support Chrome and other ECMAScript 2018 compatible browsers, you may use

```js
console.log(  // ONLY WORKS IN ECMASCRIPT 2018 COMPATIBLE JS ENVIRONMENTS
  /^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:[\s'-]\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)*$/u.test("Test'Ťĕśţ")
);
```

Java definition:

```
String pattern = "(?U)^\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+(?:[\\s'-]\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+)*$";
```

If you are using it in Java `matches()` method, remove `^` and `$` since they are redundant there.

Comment: I forgot about one thing... Surname (maybe names also, not sure) like McName... It should be enough to change ` + upper + lower +` into ` + upper + upperAndLower`, right? But what about java part?

Comment: Are you sure? I tried, but it's not working... Doesn't work for `O'Neal` and `McName`.

Comment: @Lui The `Mc` should be optional, right? Then use `String pattern = "(?U)^(?:Mc)?\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+(?:[\\s'-](?:Mc)?\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+)*$";` - no idea where you are matching a surname and first name.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is at some places "too verbose", e.g.:

- `{1}` is not needed at all. The default repetition count is just 1.
- `{0,1}` can be written shorter as `?`.
- The `\` before `'` is not needed.

You used also two cases of `(?= ... )` - *positive lookaheads*,
which are totally not needed here.

The regex proposed by *Wiktor* is almost OK, but I would change the last `*`
to `?`, because you mentioned **only one** optional surname (not many of them).

So my proposition is:

```
^[A-ZÀ-Ž][a-zà-ž]+(?:[\s'-][A-ZÀ-Ž][a-zà-ž]+)?$
```

Description:

- `^` - Start of the source string.
- `[A-ZÀ-Ž]` - A upper case letter (start of the name).
- `[a-zà-ž]+` - A seuence of lower case letters (the rest of name).
- `(?:` - A non-capturing group, needed due to `?` after it.

  - `[\s'-]` - Either a white char or apostrophe or minus
    (the seprator between name and surname).
  - `[A-ZÀ-Ž][a-zà-ž]+` - Surname - just like the name.
- `)?` - End of non-capturing group, optional. Instead of `?`,
  Wiktor proposed `*`, allowing **many** surnames.
- `$` - End of the source string.

So the non-capturing group setves as a container for:

- the separator,
- the surname.

It is optional (`?`), as the surname (together with the preceding separator)
may be absent.

Maybe `\s` should be replaced with just a space, because `\s` matches
also a `Tab` or a `'\n'` and I think, these chars should not be allowed
as separator.

Comment: The non-capturing quality of the group is not really required. So the `?:` can be omitted after the `(`.

Comment: Capturing group is not neded here, as there is no need to separately read this fragment. It serves only as "borders" of the optional area. Another reason is that capturing groups have negative impact on performance. This is why I chose the non-capturing variant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and entire explanation. Could you tell me why this one is allowed: `Łóźćż'żłóźćęą` ??

Comment: I suppose that "[A-ZÀ-Ž][a-zà-ž]" specification covers ASCII (Latin) letters and various national characters. As I see, you asked about Polish national characters. If this is not what you want, maybe you should specify the character class some other way. Maybe you should enumerate chars from your language of interest.